# String splits on new line in java script causing unexpected token errors

Tags: javascript, string

I pass a json-like string to my page using a public string and this catch:

```
var Search = <%=ListSearch %>
```

At run time you can see it has the string passed to it:[image]

This string is very large and it looks like it has to be split between two lines, I think this is causing an unexpected token error.

The last section in the top line looks as follows:

```
{id: 9589,value: "Targa Pane  (ATAR200)",MatchName: "Targa Pane",MatchAccount: "ATAR200",MatchCredit: "1.00",MatchTelephone: "(071) 6906188
```

This is forcing the new line that started to start with an open quote which was meant to be the top lines closing quote.

I do not force any new lines, its doing this by its self.

```
",MatchFax: "(012) 6533362",MatchMobile: "",MatchEmail: "mwpospy@mweb.co.za"},
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this, or where to look to resolve this type of issue?

Comment: Can you copy-paste the exact line? It's hard to read at that size...

Comment: You can try and validate your JSON with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/), this might give you some good feedback.

Comment: There should not be new line character in value, and i guess the value for the key before MatchFax has \n character

Comment: The top line starts a new line before the quote can close a value, This is why the second line starts with a new quote.

Answer (score 0):

Your json probably has an unclosed quote in it, that messes-up the whole JavaScript...

Comment: Its when the sting is split to a new line a value "384828485 has its closing " on a new line. If you see the second line in the picture starts with a "

Comment: You can see that the **MatchFax** is colored red. That means it is part of a string - so before the 'closong' quote there is one more unpaired quote...It just not seen...

Comment: This is the last item in the top line ,{id: 9589,value: "Targa Pane  (ATAR200)",MatchName: "Targa Pane",MatchAccount: "ATAR200",MatchCredit: "1.00",MatchTelephone: "(011) 6906788  as you can see there is no closing quote at the end of that number as it was moved to the next line. This is why the second line starts with a open quote.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing *new line* using

```
ListSearch.Replace("\n", "");
```

or

```
ListSearch.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")
```

Comment: this does not stop the string from slitting in java script

Comment: Try debuggin `ListSearch` in server-side and remove the _new line_ char at the backend itself

Comment: There are no new lines in the string it breaks it up during run time.